# Kibana - Joining data from multiple types in visualization

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, kibana

Currently I'm using JDBC and logstash to import my SQL database into Elasticsearch. I've got three tables, which I'm putting under the same index and using a different type for each table. For ease of explanation, the types and fields look like this:

User: {'UserID', 'UserName'}

Account: {'AccountID', 'AccountName'}

AccountUsers: {'AccountID', 'UserID'}

An account can have multiple users, and users can belong to multiple accounts. What I'm trying to do in Kibana is visualize how many users belong to each account using a bar chart and the type 'AccountUsers' (x-axis:AccountID, y-axis:Unique count of UserID). This is working fine, but I'd prefer the x-axis labels to be 'AccountName' instead of 'AccountID'. I've done some research, and it doesn't seem like any functionality exists to use these 'AccountID's to look up the actual account name in a different document type (In my case, 'Account') and display that instead. Can anybody suggest ways I will be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an elasticsearch plugin for logstash. This will allow a search of elasticsearch, and give you the ability to create a 'join', by editing the config file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.
1. While indexing write a join query in logstash script and index data to elastic search.

2.Or you can use kibi tool from SIREn solutions which is as similar to kibana there you can perform joins in elasticsearch.

Comment: I would use the Kibi tool, but annoyingly it only supports Elasticsearch up to 2.4.x. Also I'm not sure joining documents in logstash is a viable solution in my case, but I will look into it.

Comment: UPDATE: Was able to successfully use the first method. In Logstash I was able to create a new document combining fields from other existing documents in Elasticsearch. This was helpful: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-fields .